# eclipse android project: R disappears while adding menu options

Tags: android, android-layout, android-camera, android-menu

Hi In my eclipse android project, whenever i try to add a xml file named options.xml the R disappears.
This is what i did,
under res folder i created a menu folder through eclipse add option. I created a xml file under that named options.xml, its contents are,

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


<item android:title="Take Picture" android:id="@+id/camera" android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_camera" android:showAsAction="ifRoom"></item>
</menu>
```

but whenever i try to add that R.java disappears from auto-generation. I do not understand this. I closed and reopened eclipse, tried fresh projects no luck.

my layout main.xml,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"

android:orientation="horizontal">
<SurfaceView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/preview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

If I delete the menu folder R appears.

Comment: Do you have an element with `android:id="@+id/camera"` in your layout?

Comment: What API are you programming for? If you app is designed for API 10, Android 2.3.4 or earlier, `showAsAction` is forbidden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are programming for API 10 you cannot use `android:showAsAction`, that is introduced in API 11.  Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

The R.java file will get disappear if there is some error in your resource files. Probably due to name conflict, resource not found or something else.

Check the "Problems" view in eclipse, it will inform you about the problem.

Comment: This is what i get from problems, Description Resource Path Location Type
Archive for required library: 'res/menu/options.xml' in project 'CameraT' cannot be read or is not a valid ZIP file CameraT  Build path Build Path Problem

Comment: I'm wondering why the project treats your options.xml as a library?

Comment: What's your Project Build Target?

Answer (score 0):

As VoidMain already stated you have a problem in your XML. XML looks ok..so the problem can only be caused by

```
android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
```

I suppose you want the default camera icon from android resources so you have to replace the line above with

```
android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera"
```

Comment: I did it still no luck. If I delete the menu folder then R appears.